# Image is not showing in wordpress media

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

When I am uploading images in WordPress media. It shows error.
[error showing: An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqOWU.png)
And also any of the images is not showing. 
Here I click to attched image to the page but there is no image

[Not any of the images are showing here only wp loader is rotating.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQi5l.png)

This issue comes when I make a second copy of wordpress site on the same server. I have given Site URL and Home URL correctly and also given permission to the all the folder. Yet this issue not resolved. but other wordpress site is working fine on this server.

Comment: Why do you want a second copy on the same server? is there any particular reason for that?

Comment: Check upload directory permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many reasons to do not upload images in your WordPress media library.

That might be the issue of permission of your directory or as you said you have given permission already then you should check you upload path.

There are also some other steps to check and solve your issue.

Please follow [this](https://sebastian.expert/fix-wordpress-an-error-occurred-in-the-upload-please-try-again-later/) link. It will guide you step by step process and hopefully work for you.

Comment: When I checked in folder image is uploaded but it showing error. I think the problem is not in upload the problem is showing image in media